# Angular flatten observable stream

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngx-bootstrap

I have the following Angular code that calls a service that returns an Observable

```
this.dataSource = Observable.create((observer: any) => {
    observer.next(this.asyncSelected);
})
.pipe(
    mergeMap((token: string) =>
        this._animalSuffixesServiceProxy.getAll(token, undefined, undefined, undefined)
    )
);
```

The `getAll` method returns an observable in the following format:

```
{"result":{"totalCount":2,"items":[{"animalSuffix":{"name":"Test","id":1}},{"animalSuffix":{"name":"Test2","id":2}}]}}
```

Assuming that changing how the `getAll` works in not an option, I would like to know how to best pipe this response through observable operators so I can end up with a flattened observable that looks like this:

```
[{"name":"Test","id":1},{"name":"Test2","id":2}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `map` operator to process your response into the desired format. It should be like the following:

```js
this.dataSource = Observable.create((observer: any) => {
    observer.next(this.asyncSelected);
})
.pipe(
    mergeMap((token: string) =>
        this._animalSuffixesServiceProxy.getAll(token, undefined, undefined, undefined)
    ),
    map(response => response.result.items.map(item => item.animalSuffix))
);
```

This maps your response to an array of your items, with the value for each item being the response item's `animalSuffix` value.

The `map` in the `pipe()` is the RxJS operator to map over each item emitted on the observable. The other `map` is the array operator (they both behave in the same way).

Comment: Thanks for your response, it pointed me in the right direction. However I found that I had to put the `map` as a pipe **inside** the `mergeMap` on the observable response of `getAll()`. My understanding of observables is very limited but is this expected?

Comment: @tkha007 You shouldn't need to do it there. You should get the same result if you pull out your modified code you put in the `pipe` you added to your `.getAll(...)` and put it where I had it above. What were you experiencing that was different?

Comment: If i keep it as you have suggested then the tsc complains with this error `Property 'result' does not exist on type '{}'`